# Type of first parameter in object of methods

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this

```
type d = {
  (e: 'edit', value: boolean): void;
  (e: 'download', value: boolean): void;
  (e: 'delete', value: boolean): void;
}
```

I want to set the type of a function, which will accept only `'edit' | 'download' | 'delete'` i.e. all the e values of type d.

e.g.

```
function myFunc(e: ??what type??) {
}
myFunc('edit'); // valid type
myFunc('some') // invalid type
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Why -1?????????

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing your callback type by using the Actions instead.

```
type Action = "edit" | "download" | "delete";
type Callback = (e: Action, value: boolean) => void;
```

Now you can assign the type

```
function myFunc(e: Action) { ... }
```

Comment: This is the alternate I m currently using!!! but want to ready it from `type d`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `d` is an overloaded function type. Normally, you could use the `Parameters` utility type to get the type of parameters of a function easily. But `Parameters` only returns the type of the *last* overload.

But we can work around this limitation by creating our own utility type which supports `N` overloads.

```
type OverloadedParameters<T> = 
    T extends { (...args: infer R1) : any; (...args: infer R2) : any; (...args: infer R3) : any ; (...args: infer R4) : any } ? [R1, R2, R3, R4] :
    T extends { (...args: infer R1) : any; (...args: infer R2) : any; (...args: infer R3) : any } ? [R1, R2, R3] :
    T extends { (...args: infer R1) : any; (...args: infer R2) : any } ? [R1, R2] :
    T extends (...args: infer R) => any ? [R] : any
```

`OverloadedParameters` accepts up to 4 overloads. You can expand it to as many overloads as you want. Just follow the pattern.

We now get a tuple containing all the parameter types of the overloaded function `d`. All that's left to do is to index it with `number` to get a union of all the parameters and then index it with `0` to get the first element of each union element.

```
function myFunc(e: OverloadedParameters<d>[number][0]) {}

myFunc('edit') // ok
myFunc('some') // Error
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TFWJE8G0wwDLFGY0A)